# When I swipe second page just there I want to see progressdialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I have tab+swipe app on android.it s work fine. I load data from url with json on second page with asyntask method and it is work fine too.But when It loads data , I show progressbar. The problem is progress dialog is seen on first page. I want to see it only second page. How can I do this?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

here is my code

public class web_get_thread  extends AsyncTask {

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = ""; 

protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
            web_api_get_thread.this.cancel(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Set up HTTP post

        // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]); 
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
        }
      } else {
       // Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }  
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
        Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
        e3.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e4) {
        Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
        e4.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Convert response to string using String Builder  
    return builder.toString(); 
} // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)


protected void onPostExecute(String string) {

    //parse JSON data
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(string);

        this.progressDialog.dismiss();

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

    } // catch (JSONException e)


} // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
```

}

Comment: Can you show us some code snippits?

Comment: I use asyntask method and onpreexecute method I show progressdialog ,in do in background I load data from url and then on execute post I dissmiss progressdialog, it works fine ,this is in second fragment, but the dialog appear first fragment, how can I it do for just second page

Comment: Daan is asking you to edit your question and include the actual code snippets.  Not just describe the code in a comment.

Comment: I edit my question, please do not give down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the ProgressBar when it starts to load url and make it invisible when loading is finished. In order to do that you can just implement `WebViewClient` and extend `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished()` as follows:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I did a big mistake , I dont load webview I load data from url with get method. sorry about that , I am junior,

Comment: I edit my question , (ali kardeş sana mail atabilir miyim sorunu detaylı)